# SQL Query DATE format including today's date

Tags: marketing-cloud, sql

I want to run a query to get the customers who purchased from the 27th of August to the second of September(today)

This is what I have so far = but this doesn't give me the day of today and if I increase the  counting back days to 7 it will give me the 26th date which isn't what I want.

```
AND 
convert(date, [OrderDate]) >= convert(date, (getutcdate() - 6))
```

I've also tried

```
AND 
cast(GetDate() As Date) = '2019-09-02'
```

but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Can you see any records with OrderDate = today, when you inspect the data extension manually? There is nothing wrong with your query.

Comment: if I only do cast(GetDate() As Date) = '2019-09-02', I'm getting everything, purchase of all time

Comment: Have you tried: *WHERE cast(OrderDate As Date) >= CAST(DATEADD(DAY, -6, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, GETUTCDATE)) As Date)*

Comment: it doesn't work unfortunately
The only thing that works is AND convert(date, [OrderDate]) >= convert(date, (getutcdate() - 6)) but I'm not getting the date of today

Comment: Are you sure you have records from today in your data extension?

Comment: yes, hundred percent